# Can multiple looper ICs (ISD1820) share one single electret microphone?

Tags: audio, electret

I'm using multiple of [these](https://www.openimpulse.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/wpsc/downloadables/ISD1820-Voice-Recording-and-Playback-Chip-Datasheet.pdf) ICs to create a simple audio looper. Can they share the same single electret microphone, or should they each have their own? Multiple ICs may have brief overlap of use of the microphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the IC does not supply bias current to the microphone, it should be alright. It may have slightly higher noise levels and be quieter.